# x64 disassembly from memory

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, disassembly

I'm working on a JIT compiler on x64; some of the code is necessarily operating system specific, so I'm concentrating on the Windows version right now, with the Linux port to come later. For debugging purposes, I'm going to need some kind of disassembler (written by someone other than me, so that I'm not just echoing my mistakes) to check what my generated machine code really corresponds to.

What's the easiest way to get a disassembly from a chunk of machine code in the memory of a C++ program, on 64-bit Windows?

- Visual C++ certainly has the wherewithal to disassemble my generated code for me, if I run my program under the debugger. Is there a way to get it to do so?
- libopcodes has the capability in principle, but it's a Linux library; is there an easy way to get it to compile with Visual C++?
- dumpbin can disassemble code that's been written to disk, but seems to want a proper object file wrapper. Is there a way around that, or how easy is it to create a minimal wrapper?

Or is there some other option I'm overlooking?

Comment: Just use the debugger's Disassembly window.  Focus on having the jitter dump enough info so you'll know what to put in the Address box.

Comment: Yeah, that turns out to be the most practical solution.